# Как узнать дату изменения файла, не скачивая его

Tags: java

У меня есть файл. Для примера будет этот файл — [файл](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B__xB2sZtgF_UVNaeE9wbXhwR2M). Мне нужно не загружая этот файл узнать дату последнего изменения, используя Java (любой библиотекой, любым способом). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Это есть в Google Drive API, ищите в документации.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#modifiedTime